# RegEx for matching latitude and longitude function

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

I have a latitude and longitude data on my file, which I am trying to call by a [convertor function](https://ideone.com/h2xwAc).

I am trying to add function for the `$result60` line and it does not work. I am trying to pass values for the function, so it would calculate the correct latitude and longitude degrees using DM method.

#### Attempt

```
$re60 = '/([EW])([0-9][0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])/s';
$str60 = 'E16130';
//$subst60 = '\\3\\2\\1';
$subst60 = DMS2Decimal($degr = \\2, $mins = \\3, $secs = 0, $dir = \\1);
$result60 = preg_replace($re60, $subst60, $str60);
echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result60;
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I am trying to add function for the $result60 = .....line"? Can you please edit your question with more detailed information and a sample of the code you have tried and had a problem with.

Comment: [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) perhaps? // (Help appreciation / nagging / thanks do not belong in the question.)

Comment: Edited the whole question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/G1jlHc/1) to divide your input string into 3 groups, where group `$1`, `$2` and `$3` can be called by your DMS method to return `$decimal`.

#### RegEx

```
/([EWSN])([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})/s
```

[image: RegEx]

#### Code

```
$str60 = 'E16130';
preg_match_all('/([EWSN])([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})/s', $str60, $matches);
$result60 = DMS2Decimal($degrees = (int) $matches[2][0], $minutes = (int) $matches[3][0], $seconds = 10, $direction = strtolower($matches[1][0]));

echo "The result of the substitution:  y: " . $result60;

function DMS2Decimal($degrees = 0, $minutes = 0, $seconds = 0, $direction = 'n')
{
    //converts DMS coordinates to decimal
    //returns false on bad inputs, decimal on success

    //direction must be n, s, e or w, case-insensitive
    $d = strtolower($direction);
    $ok = array('n', 's', 'e', 'w');

    //degrees must be integer between 0 and 180
    if (!is_numeric($degrees) || $degrees < 0 || $degrees > 180) {
        $decimal = false;
    }
    //minutes must be integer or float between 0 and 59
    elseif (!is_numeric($minutes) || $minutes < 0 || $minutes > 59) {
        $decimal = false;
    }
    //seconds must be integer or float between 0 and 59
    elseif (!is_numeric($seconds) || $seconds < 0 || $seconds > 59) {
        $decimal = false;
    } elseif (!in_array($d, $ok)) {
        $decimal = false;
    } else {
        //inputs clean, calculate
        $decimal = $degrees + ($minutes / 60) + ($seconds / 3600);

        //reverse for south or west coordinates; north is assumed
        if ($d == 's' || $d == 'w') {
            $decimal *= -1;
        }
    }

    return $decimal;
}
```

#### Output

```
The result of the substitution:  y: 161.5027777777
```

Comment: If I run var_dump($matches); I see all changes in my data (Appx 600 of them) But how do I convert and display the whole page, with all other stuff on the page? Thx